# Visual studio does not load class into editor if you check it out while debugging the solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

We are using Visual Studio 2010 with Team Foundation server 2010 for source control.  Our VB solution has several projects.  (one EXE and a few DLLs).

Here is the issue:
1) Programmer A makes a change to a VB class and checks it in.

2) Programmer B, who is debugging the application, goes to that class in the editor and checks it out.

Immediately he gets a message saying that "Your action caused a check out of the file(s) such and such, and a new version from source control has been loaded in the development environment."  When you say OK, every line in the class is underlined with a tooltip "Unable to apply this change while debugging"

So he stops debugging.

3) The change that the programmer A has made was checked out and is on disk but is not loaded into the editor.  So if Programmer B alters the file and checks it in, the changes that Programmer A made are lost.

4) This does not happen if the solution is paused.  Also if you close the class.vb and reopen it, it retrives the new one from disk.

We have lost several code changes because people check out recently updated code while debugging.

Any adeas as to how to make it work properly, that is how we can get the newly checked out source code to load in the editor when the program is debugging

Thanks,

Stephen Simpson